# Anyway to use Kendall's Tau C-Coef when using ggpairs()?

Tags: r

Just like the title. The ggpairs function defaults to pearson's r and does not provide a argument to make the correlation type to either spearman or kendall.

Anybody know of a way to do this?

Comment: This might be better placed on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8):

Not sure what the problem is. Did you read the `ggpairs` documentation?

The following works just fine for calculating Pearson, Spearman and/or Kendall correlation coefficients in `ggpairs`:

```
# Generate some sample data
set.seed(2017);
samples <- lapply(1:4, function(x)
    runif(1, min = -1, max = 1) * seq(0, 1, len = 100) + rnorm(100, 0,     0.1));
names(samples) <- paste0("S", 1:4);
df <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, samples);

require(GGally);
ggpairs(data = df, upper = list(continuous = wrap("cor", method = "pearson")));
ggpairs(data = df, upper = list(continuous = wrap("cor", method = "spearman")));
ggpairs(data = df, upper = list(continuous = wrap("cor", method = "kendall")));
```

For example, the last line produces a pairwise scatterplot showing Kendall's rank correlation coefficients in the upper triangular:
[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Maurits.  I still find reading the documentation for some packages and functions to be very cryptic. Simply didn't understand this one. I stumbled because the other functions such as ggscatmat include a "method" as one of the argument. I didn't see that this option was embedded in the "upper = ect." argument within ggpairs.

Comment: Also, I did upvote but it doesn't show due to my low post count.

Comment: No worries @nick-b, glad to help. I know the feeling about package documentation being "cryptic" at times. The ggplot syntax is very powerful but certainly also idiosyncratic, especially in the beginning...

Comment: PS. If this solves your question, please accept this answer to mark the question as solved.